# CRON task doesn't work on Amazon EC2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-ec2, cron, whenever

I prepared a simple task for testing CRON jobs on Amazon EC2:

### schedule.rb

```
set :output, "/home/a/b/current/log/cron_log.log"

 every 5.minutes do
   #command "/usr/bin/some_great_command"
   #runner "MyModel.some_method"
   #rake "some:great:rake:task"
   puts "It's working !!!"
   runner "User.grab_first_user", :environment => 'development'
   runner "User.grab_first_user", :environment => 'production'
 end
```

### user.rb

```
  def self.grab_first_user
    user = User.first
    puts user.inspect
    if user
      NotificationMailer.send_info(user.email).deliver
    end
  end
```

### notification_mailer.rb <-- this is workin

```
  def send_info(user_email)
    @user_email = user_email
    mail(:to => 'my@emaill.com', :subject => "[CRON Test]")
  end
```

When I check the `crontab` file, I see there this CRON task, but the email is never sent - the method is never called.
When I manually call that method, then is everything working (also the email is sent), but the method is never called by CRON.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Most likely you have not written your tasks into cron. Have you done `bundle exec whenever -w`?

Comment: It's possibly that the cron daemon isn't started as well.

Comment: `kobaltz` - yes, this is working.

Comment: `Kevin` - how can I start it? And how can I check if the cron daemon is running or not?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have not written your tasks into cron.

Have you done `bundle exec whenever -w`?

It's also possible that the cron daemon isn't started as well.